# Invalid permission to use gpedit.msc

Tags: windows, windows-10, virtual-machine, gpedit

For some reason every time I try launching gpedit to get a VirtualMachine up and running I keep getting permission errors which to my knowledge should not appear.

I am running Windows 10 Pro, 64bit

My account is a administrator account, there are no other accounts on this machine, other things like services.msc work fine and according to the file permissions I should be fine

[Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/njYn0.jpg)

Comment: Screen shot of error message please

Comment: @Facebook added it to the original post

Comment: Too bad it's not translated in English so I (and others) could tell with some accuracy what the message state in terms that we understand.

Answer (score 0):

At what point does gpedit.msc deny permission when setting up the VM? Does it just prompt "Access Denied" with no error code?

If you are able to launch gpedit there must be a policy missing for your Admin account, or Virtualization Technology may be disabled on the BIOS.

Double check your local policies for related permissions as Administrator, then apply.

Force the changes to apply by running cmd line as Admin. and enter;

gpupdate /f

Restart, attempt the VM install, if errors occur note the task performed and any error codes. Check BIOS for enable VM support if needed.

Comment: VMWare starts linking me to [this page](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2146361) when startin a VM in which I need to edit some settings in the group policies.
I am indeed admin and all the rights should be setup right and I had no other issues until now,
I am going to look if I have Virtualization enables or not I also added some images to the original post that show that there is indeed no error code

Comment: @SentryCrafter - Looks like the link you provided has a possible solution with instructions to change the Local policy & Disable Credential Guard. It's a quite a few steps but are easy to apply. This is the link to the Knowledge Based article for VM.                                                                                                                                                    https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2146361

Comment: the link to the guide does not fix my issue

Comment: The only thing I could add to the guide in your link would be to apply gpupdate /f in the cmd line after following all the steps to make sure it's all applied.  Then fully power down, (not restart) just in case lower level operations need to apply. Then restart, check your BIOS for Virtual settings and disable any Trusted Platform or machine management settings that are in the BIOS/UEFI.